# Specify fields to search into in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this json:

```
body: {
    "sort" : queryBody.sort,
    "query": { 
        "bool": { 
            "must": [
                {"query_string": { "query": '"mystring"' } }
            ],
            "filter":  { 
                query_string: { query: '"mystring"' } } search-filter [{"term":{"accessType":1}}]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This json seems to be searching inside all the fields in the document. How can I specify the exact fields I want to search into according to current json?
I have seen resources explaining you should add the "fields"-array. But I could not find a structure that lookes like mine, which have the schema

```
query.bool.must.query_string
```

So I don't really understand where to place the fields-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You need to add `fields` array.Try following query:

```
 {
  "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
             "fields": [
                "field1" ,
                "field2"
             ], 
              "query": "this AND that OR thus"
            }
          }
       ]
      }
    }
 }
```